# Cabal fails to build detailed-0.9 test suite

Tags: haskell, build, cabal, cabal-install, unix-ar

I'm trying to build a package with a single test suite:

```
name:                  test
version:               0.1.0.0
build-type:            Simple
cabal-version:         >=1.10

library
  -- exposed-modules:     
  build-depends:       base
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  default-language:    Haskell2010

Test-Suite tests
  type:                detailed-0.9
  test-module:         Tests
  build-depends:       base, Cabal
  hs-source-dirs:      tests
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Here's what happens:

```
PS C:\temporary\test> cabal configure --enable-tests
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring test-0.1.0.0...
PS C:\temporary\test> cabal build
Building test-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing library test-0.1.0.0...
In-place registering test-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing test suite 'tests' for test-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Tests            ( tests\Tests.hs, dist\build\Tests.o )
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0\mingw\bin\ar.exe: dist\build\Tests.o: No such file or directory
PS C:\temporary\test>
```

I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit, with Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0. I have installed MSYS, and the only MinGW on the path is GHC's. Also, all git binaries are after MSYS and MinGW on the path so they do not conflict. Any advice is appreciated.

---

**Update**: It appears that building tests works fine when using `type: exitcode-stdio-1.0`.